# how to contact data in sqlserver?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i get the data like this

**Select Service_id from the application_data**

[image]

**select id,name from service_type**

[image]

i am trying to get the output like this, based on the id data should concate like this

[image]

I tried to get the data in functions

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[get_service_type] 
(@serviceid VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql varchar(500), @s1 varchar(500)
    SET @s1=( select '('''+REPLACE(''+@serviceid+'',',',''',''')+''')' as Str)  
    DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)   
    SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + name 
    FROM service_type  
    WHERE id !=0 and id in(@serviceid)  
RETURN @s1
END
```

**`select dbo.dbo.serviceType_Split('23,24,25'))`**

But still i am facing the  problem..

guide me how can i achieve this..

Comment: Comma separated values? Don't store data like that, it will only cause you lots of problems. One value per row is the SQL way!

Comment: Yeah i know the problem......Its database has been designed like this... i was working on some new modules...it has been developed by some other developer.... that way i am facing problem...can you suggest me how can i get the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CREATE FUNCTION` return `ID, Nam`e for each row in `application_data`

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCSVStr2Table(@CSVStr VARCHAR(1000)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
 AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (service_id VARCHAR(50), service_name VARCHAR(100))
    DECLARE @SubStr VARCHAR(100), @i INT
    DECLARE @List_service_name VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(',', @CSVStr, 0)
    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SubStr = LEFT(@CSVStr,@i-1)
        INSERT INTO @Tbl
        SELECT * FROM service_type WHERE id = @SubStr

        SET @CSVStr = SUBSTRING(@CSVStr, @i+1, 1000)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(',', @CSVStr, 0)
    END 

    INSERT INTO @Tbl
    SELECT * FROM service_type WHERE id = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CSVStr))
    SELECT @List_service_name = COALESCE(@List_service_name + ', ', '') + service_name
    FROM @Tbl
    WHERE service_name IS NOT NULL
    RETURN @List_service_name
END
```

Then, select:

```
SELECT service_id
FROM application_data
CROSS APPLY fnCSVStr2Table(service_id)
```

Comment: i am getting error when i execute the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull:
Add a comma at the front and the back of service_id in application_data table and use PATINDEX to find the id surrounded by comma's

Comment: Can you provide me an example with this data ?

Comment: If I had the time I would be happy to. You would still have to loop through the records to combine the data in the service_name though...
It is not a pleasant job when you are faced with these kinds of datasets.